# Android Studio properly links app with -lGLESv3 for 64 bit arm, but not 32 bit arm

Tags: android, android-studio, linker, arm, opengl-es-3.0

I have an Android app that uses OpenGL ES3. I can build (and run) it for my 64-bit android device.

When I try to build it for 32bit instead, the linker cannot find libGLESv3 library and fails to build.

In my app's gradle, I have:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.steenriver.biplane"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 113
    versionName "1.13"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        //abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            //ldFlags "-Wl,-fuse-ld=gold"
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -DANDROID=1 -DPLAY=1 -DUSEES3=1 -DLOGTAG=biplane"
            arguments "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm"
        }
    }

}
```

Using **arm64-v8a**, there is no problem.

Using **armeabi-v7a** (after doing a clean project), I get:

*/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold:* **error: cannot find -lGLESv3**

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu. I specify -lGLESv3 in my CMakeLists.txt as:

```
target_link_libraries(biplane
  gpg
  pi
  uif
  gbase
  dblunt
  gpgoap
  opende
  freealut
  openal
  EGL
  GLESv3
  OpenSLES
  android
  log
  z
  m
)
```

And the complete command line for the linker is:

```
/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -marm -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -DANDROID=1 -DPLAY=1 -DUSEES3=1 -DLOGTAG=biplane -DDEBUG -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libbiplane.so -o /home/bram/apps/Proto/Biplane/AndroidProject/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libbiplane.so CMakeFiles/biplane.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/biplane.dir/androidsupport.cpp.o CMakeFiles/biplane.dir/android_native_app_glue.c.o CMakeFiles/biplane.dir/StateManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/biplane.dir/scorekeeper.cpp.o  /home/bram/src/gpg-cpp-sdk/android/lib/gnustl/armeabi-v7a/libgpg.a /home/bram/apps/Proto/Biplane/AndroidProject/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/PI/output/libpi.a /home/bram/apps/Proto/Biplane/AndroidProject/app/.externalNativeBuild/uif/output/libuif.a /home/bram/apps/GBase/src/output/libgbase.a /home/bram/src/dutch-blunt/src/output/libdblunt.a /home/bram/src/GPGOAP/output/libgpgoap.a /home/bram/src/opende/output/libopende.a /home/bram/src/freealut/src/output/libfreealut.a /home/bram/src/openal-soft/jni/output/libopenal.a -lEGL -lGLESv3 -lOpenSLES -landroid -llog -lz -lm -lm "/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused by minSdkVersion 16.

Android only supports OpenGLES3 since SDK 18 and later.

I've set minSdkVersion to 19 and now the armeabi-v7a links as well. I'm not sure how the arm64-v8a managed to link.

Comment: 64-bit arm always builts at least for native api level 21, that's how it worked.